# Flex custom components, events and scope

Tags: apache-flex, events, scope

I'm starting to give up on the Flex forums so I'l re-post here and see how things go. Long time lurker, first time poster ;-)

I'm trapping keyboard events on the stage and dispatching custom events through a framework (Mate, though I don't know that this is an important issue), but I'm pretty confused by the scope. The structure is:

--application (traps keyboard events and dispatches custom event

```
 --  mainPanel (receives dispatched events but mainCalendar (a child element) 
     is null on debugging. Obviously if I try to call a public method on 
     mainCalendar it errors out, even though it's a child of mainPanel. 
     However, mainCalendar is NOT null IF I use 
     FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.mainPanel.mainCalendar.
     Outerdocument and parentDocument do not expose mainCalendar either, BTW

     --  mainCalendar (a custom component inside mainPanel with public methods. 
         Creation policy is 'all' and it's visible and exists long before I 
         trap any keystrokes at the top level)
```

Could someone take a minute and explain why the mainCalendar is out of scope when mainPanel receives a custom event, even though mainCalendar is a child of mainPanel. Is there a better way to manage the events so I don't have to always address the component via the topLevelApplication?

Thanks

Comment: Not looks like scope problem, more of timing. Which event do you use when component is null? (Is it before or after `initialize` event?)

Comment: alxx is right; it could be that mainCalendar is not created yet, when you try to access it for the first time. Even after initialize is fired, it could be that Flex hasn't created it yet (for example, if the component is not visible)

Comment: You are right when you say that you shouldn't be accessing topLevelApplication. That's exactly what events are for: any component can listen for any event. But since I do not know exactly what you're trying to do, I can only point you to the [basics of event handling in AS](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html). Also, since you're using Mate, I would guess it has some event handling functionalities too, so you may want to read up on the [docs](http://mate.asfusion.com/page/documentation/) there too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The event fired is a custom event dispatched from another component through Mate eventmap and it's received by the target component fine. If it were a timing issue, I would expect that to be a problem early in the component life cycle, however this occurs long after the calendar with which I'm working has been used, including drag and drop. So I know the mainCalendar is created because I interact with it on several things long before capturing keystrokes to try to mimic what I'm already doing with a context menu. However, I appreciate the comments.

Comment: Technically, `mainPanel.mainCalendar` is a property of `mainPanel`, not necessarily a child. Is it initialized? Is it overwritten to null at some moment? Custom event by themselves should not cause reference loss.

Comment: I see it visually and can drag and drop visual items on the mainCalendar successfully before I try to invoke the keystroke trap. Would it, by definition, be initialized if I've interacted with it graphically before catching the keystrokes leading to the error? Or should I somehow reference it in the script before calling a method on it?

Comment: OK, you all were right, at least I assume so. It was a timing issue that was easily resolved by doing a check of if mainCalendar != null. I still don't totally understand how a first event gets to the handler but an apparent second event arrives and mainCalendar is not null upon receiving the event. In fact, it fires off the function a third time so I  had to use event.stopImmediatePropogation(), which also makes me a little crazy wondering why I have to manually stop events, but that's a different issue. Thanks. This is my first time using Stackoverflow so let me know how to mark as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(creating answer so this question could be marked as answered)*
Usually, when reference to component is null and it should not, this means component isn't created yet. This might have place before application `initialize` event or if component's parent isn't visible and not validated.

Comment: I agree and, by implication to me, the instance of the calendar with which I'm interacting with visually before calling the problem function must be (I'm thinking) a different instance of the calendar than the original, but that's a topic for another question. Thanks.